# quick way to do def pair_sum()

Tags: python, function, sum

Does anyone know how to do this in a simple and effective way?
Thanks

Define a function called pair_sum() which takes two inputs: a list of integers and a total.

The function should return a list of tuples, where each value in the tuple is a unique value from the input list, and where the sum of the tuple elements equals the total. Each pair of values in the input list that sums to the total should only appear once in the output list. For example, if the input list is [3, 2, 1] and the total is 4, then the output list will only contain the tuple (3, 1) and not the tuple (1, 3).  In other words, if (i, j) is a tuple in the output list, then i should appear to the left of j in the input list.

For example:

Test    Result

```
print(pair_sum([4, 6, 2, 7, 3], 10))
[(4, 6), (7, 3)]
print(pair_sum([4, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2, 6, 11, 1, 5, 10], 14))
[(4, 10), (8, 6), (9, 5), (3, 11)]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) before asking homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@xaovnumwsercz, I proposed this version.

```
def pair_sum(numbers, target):
    answer = []
    for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
        if target-num in numbers[i+1:]:
            answer.append((num,target-num))
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pair_sum (numbers, pairSum):

    resultSet=[];
    newNumbers = sorted(numbers);

    i = 0;
    j = len(newNumbers)-1;

    while i < len(newNumbers) and j >= 0:

        if newNumbers[i] + newNumbers[j] == pairSum and i != j:   
            if (newNumbers[j], newNumbers[i]) not in resultSet and numbers.index(newNumbers[i]) < numbers.index(newNumbers[j]):    
                resultSet.append((newNumbers[i], newNumbers[j]))
                numbers.remove(newNumbers[i]);
                numbers.remove(newNumbers[j])

            i = i + 1;
            j = j - 1;
        elif newNumbers[i] + newNumbers[j] < pairSum:
            i = i + 1;
        else: 
            j = j - 1;

    return (resultSet);
```

Comment: According to the author, seems that you can't sort the input.

Comment: It's not mentioned anywhere that input cannot be sorted, besides sorting makes this efficient.

Comment: "In other words, if (i, j) is a tuple in the output list, then i should appear to the left of j in the input list."

Comment: Hey pok fung Chan, I got it, please have a look at updated answer. I am using original array to find if indexes are in order. Please suggest a better approach, I feel there certainly could be. Thanks!

Comment: umm... Seems that newNumbers is not defined.

Comment: Hey, since I cannot comment on your answer being a new user, I'm saying it here. Your answer is amazing, something new to learn. Thanks!